# Spring-context configuration - namespace

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jax-ws

I am trying to configure spring project with hibernate and JAX-WS.

I encountered a problem in servlet-context file - it is showing to me that it cannot locate a namespace for spring-webmvc, but I do have it in pom.

Stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
```

Beggining of servlet-context file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd 
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">
```

Important elements in pom.xml (it's not all the file - I've cut the things that in my opinion can matter) :

```
 <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any help appreciated.

@EDIT:

I've realized that when I remove JAX-WS dependency from the pom file, everything seems to work (but then I cannot use it...) :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd`, then you will be good

**update**

if you are using mvc namespace, you cannot remove this for sure, then define it properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Comment: After doing that annotation-driven doesn't work: Line 17 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 23; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'annotation-driven'.

Comment: JAX-WS dependency is causing this error - when I remove it, everything works fine, but then I cannot use this jar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not having spring-mvc jar in project. If you are not using spring mvc related functionality then remove the mvc related schema.
else add the spring mvc jar.

Comment: I am using annotation-driven - I guess it is using spring-mvc. I have in my pom spring-webmvc and in Maven Dependencies I can see that it is added.